# how to use template "inheritance" to avoid boilerplate code when binding C++ to python with pybind11

Tags: pybind11

I managed to bind template definitions doing

```
 py::class_<T<a>>(m, "Ta")
 py::class_<T<b>>(m, "Tb")
 ...
```

where T is the template class and `a` and `b` typenames defining the template. But the problem I have tells me that this is not the really good way to expose these template definitions, because now I am forced to duplicate code for all the functions and parameters of the template class T:

```
 py::class_<T<a>>(m, "Ta")
   .def(py::init<string, string>())
   .def("do_smthg", &T<a>::do_sthg)
   ...;
 py::class_<T<b>>(m, "Tb")
   .def(py::init<string, string>())
   .def("do_smthg", &T<b>::do_sthg)
   ...;
```

when class T itself for instance has `do_smthg`, that I would then expect to have to define only once. I tried to browse the doc and the web, but I failed to find the right pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You may just create a simple helper function that instantiates a list of templates, like following:

```cpp
template <typename x, typename ... Tail, typename ModT>
void ApplyTemplate(ModT & m, std::vector<std::string> names) {
    py::class_<T<x>>(m, names.at(0))
        .def(py::init<string, string>())
        .def("do_smthg", &T<x>::do_sthg)
    ;
    names.erase(names.begin());
    if constexpr(sizeof...(Tail) > 0)
        ApplyTemplate<Tail...>(m, names);
}
```

Now call this function within module context with all possible arguments to template:

```cpp
PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
    ApplyTemplate<a, b>(m, {"Ta", "Tb"});
}
```

If for some reason your `T` template is not available within `ApplyTemplate` context then you may pass it as a `template <typename> typename` argument:

```cpp
template <template <typename> typename T, typename x, typename ... Tail, typename ModT>
void ApplyTemplate(.....
```

---

Instead of function you can also use a simple macro:

```cpp
PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
    // Define macro
    #define MY_CLASS(param, name) \
        py::class_<T<param>>(m, name) \
            .def(py::init<string, string>()) \
            .def("do_smthg", &T<param>::do_sthg) \
        ;
    
    // Use macro
    MY_CLASS(a, "Ta");
    MY_CLASS(b, "Tb");

    // Remove macro    
    #undef MY_CLASS
}
```

Comment: thanks @Arty I tried to follow your example but the syntax is puzzling me. First the template function has to be outside the module context if I understand well. But then m is undefined no? Second I am not sure I understand the ..Tail syntax you used. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: @Johanncohen-tanugi I just didn't compile my code on real example. Of course you have to pass `m` as function parameter (just fixed my answer). Also you may use Lambda functions if you want to define function within context of module definition. `... Tail` means that template accepts any number of parameters, for example if you have `template <typename ... Args> void f() {}` then you can call this function with `f<>();` or `f<int>();` or `f<int, bool>();` or `f<int, bool, char>();`, in other words with any number of template parameters. `...` stands for "any" amount.

Comment: I just realized that this is C++17, which is too recent for my library.

Comment: I removed the constexpr and tail recursion, and I think I made it to work. Thanks again!

Comment: @Johanncohen-tanugi Alternatively, the simplest form how you can repeat same code several times is by using macros, you just define a macro with all the lines of code of `py::class_<T<x>>(...` and then call it several times, for example you can call a macro `MY_CLASS(a, "Ta");    MY_CLASS(b, "Tb");` . Macro body will contain all necessary lines of code of `py::class_<T<x>>(...` and template param name and class name you put as macro params `(a, "Ta")`. Just modified my answer above, added Part 2 of answer where I show full example with using macro, please put a look!